# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason I get an "Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'" error.
I tryed to install and uninstall it but it didn't fix the problem.
"rm -rf node_modules" and "npm i react-router-dom" don't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import REDBAR from './linije/crvena';
import WHITEBAR from './linije/bijela';
import ABOUTUS from './pages/aboutus';
import MEMBERSHIP from './pages/membership';
import CONTACTS from './pages/contacts';
import SM from './pages/slavicmovement';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {





return (

<div>
<WHITEBAR/>
<Router>
<div className="GS" id="GS">

<MEMBERSHIP/>
<ABOUTUS/>
<CONTACTS/>
<SM/>







</div>
</Router>
<REDBAR/>

</div>


);
}



export default App;
```

Comment: `npm list react-router-dom` what do you get?

Comment: nikolai@0.1.0 H:\work\nikolaiREACT\nikolai
`-- (empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something was bugged.
I restarted my pc and the "npm i react-router-dom" command worked.